# Model averaging for glmmTMB beta family

Tags: r, glmmtmb, mumin, beta-distribution

Apologies if this is not the right venue for this post....

I recently dredged some beta family models using glmmTMB, but have received this error message when trying to use `model.avg()`:

> Error in t.default(z[match(coefNames, fixCoefNames(rownames(z))), ]) : argument is not a matrix

The only documentation for this issue I've come across is from one of the glmmTMB vignettes:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/model_evaluation.pdf

> 2.5.1 issues

> may not work for Beta models because the family component (“beta”)
> is not identical to the name of the family function ( beta_family() )?
> (Kamil Bartón, pers. comm.)

Is there any sort of work-around for this issue? Would this be related to the lack of model weights in dredge output for beta distribution models?

Thank you.

Comment: Could we have a [mcve] please ... ??